# Sum of integrals probably converges to $\ln(2)$ (Seemous 2018-2019)

Tags: real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series, contest-math, improper-integrals

I was trying to solve [the fourth problem of SEEMOUS 2019](https://www.fte-uacg.bg/seemous2019/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/seemous-problems.pdf).
It goes as follows:

> (a) Let $n\geq1$ be an integer. Calculate $$ \int_0^1 x^{n-1}\ln x\,dx $$

I have proved that  $$ \int_0^1 x^{n-1}\ln x \,dx= -\displaystyle \frac{1}{n^2} .$$
I need help (or some guidance) on

> (b)
> Evaluate $$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\left( \frac{1}{(n+1)^2}- \frac{1}{(n+2)^2}+ \frac{1}{(n+3)^2}-\ldots\right).
> $$

I tested the sum and for $n=10000$ and it was really close to $\ln2$.

To calculate $\int_0^1x^{n-1}\ln x \ dx$, we write $x=e^{-t}$ for $t\in[0,\infty)$.  So
$$I=\int_0^1x^{n-1}\ln x\ dx =-\int_0^\infty e^{-(n-1)t}\ t\ e^{-t}\ dt\,.$$
That is,
$$I=-\int_0^\infty t e^{-nt}\ dt = -\frac{1}{n^2}\int_0^\infty s^{2-1} e^{-s}\ ds\,,$$
where $s=nt$.  Thus,
$$I=-\frac1{n^2}\Gamma(2)=-\frac1{n^2}(2-1)!=-\frac1{n^2}\,.$$

Answer (score 6):

Using the identity $\int_0^1 x^{n+k-1}\,dx=\frac{1}{n+k}$ we have

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^{k-1}\frac{1}{(n+k)^2}&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^{k-1}\int_0^1 x^{n+k-1}\,dx\,\int_0^1 y^{n+k-1}\,dy\\\\
&=\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-xy)^n\,\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-xy)^k\,dx\\\\
&=\int_0^1\int_0^1 \frac{1}{(1+xy)^2}\,dx\,dy\\\\\
&=\int_0^1 \frac{1}{1+y}\,dy\\\\
&=\log(2)
\end{align}$$

as was to be shown!

Answer (score 3):

\begin{eqnarray*}
S&=& \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n(\displaystyle \frac{1}{(n+1)^2}-\displaystyle \frac{1}{(n+2)^2}+\displaystyle \frac{1}{(n+3)^2}-...) \\
&=& \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} (-1)^{m} \frac{1}{(n+m+1)^2}  
\end{eqnarray*}
Let $i=n+m+1$ we get $i$ ... $i$ times ... so
\begin{eqnarray*}
S=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{i+1}  \frac{i}{i^2}   = \cdots.
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by saying:  we get $ i... i $ times

Comment: You will get the term $1/1^2$ once, $-1/2^2$ twice, ... $1/i^2$ ... $i$ times.